# Why are my bundled files not working in ASP.Net MVC Core?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have bundled all of my files by selecting them (in the order I load them in  my layout file), right clicking and choosing "Bundle & Minifier" -> "Bundle and Minify files.

Now my layout file has these environments sections:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/app/modules/appNameModule.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/constants/appNameConstants.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controllers/appNameController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controllers/employeesController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controllers/nonEmployeesController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controllers/organizationsController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controllers/casesController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/Filters/customFilters.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/app/bundle_angular.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

When I run from development in VS 2015, I am in the development environment and it works.
I set up a System Environment file for my local IIS by going to Computer Environment variables and setting up ASPNET_ENV = "Staging" to run that environment in my local IIS.
I know it's the right environment because I've been testing all morning to get my DeveloperException Pages working in the Staging environment.

But now when I publish files to my local IIS, my Staging environment, I get several errors that look like this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/   $injector/modulerr?p0=lerd&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A289%3A428
at angular.js:4387
at m (angular.js:336)
at g (angular.js:4348)
at eb (angular.js:4274)
at d (angular.js:1630)
at Zd (angular.js:1545)
at angular.js:28361
at HTMLDocument.a (angular.js:2998)
at HTMLDocument.c (angular.js:3273)
```

Does anyone know what this means?

### Update 1:

Thanks for the comment below from Pankaj Parkar about injecting the dependancies via DI.
My coworker another developer on the project mentioned this and he made the change already to our main Angular controller adding in the DI as the second parameter here:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("employeesController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'employeesUrl', 'unionHoursUrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, employeesUrl, unionHoursUrl) {
```

I'll look through all of our Angular Controllers and see if we have this everywhere.

Another question.  Do we need the single quotes in the Dependencies param? And just not the factory function part?

Comment: You have missed to followed `DI` injection pattern, you could do
1. Use Array Inline Annotation
2. Do use `$inject` to define dependency array, refer [docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: yes, i had the same problem man, the bundle execution changes the name of module in parameters funcions and it crashes the angular js logic. The names of modules can't be changed. Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that is the answer Pankaj.  I just had to follow that pattern all the way through all of my controllers.